# How can I see who reordered the teamcity build queue?

Tags: teamcity

If I bump something to the top of the queue, how can I see who moves it down or places something in front of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of this being visible in the GUI.

If nothing else, this is logged into the server log. You'll find it at `<TeamCity Server home>/logs/teamcity-server.log` (it may also have log-rotated to e.g. `teamcity-server.log.1` or been cleaned up completely). In that log, search for a message in this format:

```
[2015-09-24 06:49:02,275]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Build
queue order changed by 'dylanbob' (Dylan, Bob: Highway 61) {id=9}, old
order: [Queued build {Build promotion {promotion id=474526,configuration=Foo
{id=Foo, internal id=bt523}}, item id=474526}, Queued build {Build promotion
{promotion id=474524,configuration=Bar {id=Bar, internal id=bt601}}, item
id=474524}], new order: [Queued build {Build promotion {promotion
id=474524,configuration=Bar {id=Bar, internal id=bt601}}, item id=474524},
Queued build {Build promotion {promotion id=474526,configuration=Foo
{id=Foo, internal id=bt523}}, item id=474526}]
```